# Extracting mono-4.8.0.382.tar results in can't remove old file error

Tags: linux, tar, embedded-linux

I am working on custom minimal embedded Linux distro and I've downloaded [mono](https://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/) using `wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-4.8.0.382.tar.bz2`. The download finished without problems, however, when I try to unpack archive with `tar -xvvf mono-4.8.0.382.tar.bz2`, I get following error:

```
tar: can't remove old file mono-4.8.0/external/buildtools/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Build.Tasks.Packaging/src/FrameworkLists/.NETPor: Is a directory
```

What did I miss since I've rexecuted same command on host machine with `Debian 8` and unarchiving finished without any errors?
I've also thought the SD card has ran out of space, but this is not the problem:

```
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                 6.6G    109.0M      6.2G   2% /
devtmpfs                470.5M      4.0K    470.5M   0% /dev
tmpfs                   503.4M    144.0K    503.2M   0% /run
tmpfs                   503.4M     40.0K    503.3M   0% /var/volatile
/dev/mmcblk0p1          503.9M      4.5M    473.9M   1% /run/media/mmcblk0p1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the straightforward solution, however, I've unpacked compressed file on host machine and copied extracted contents to microsd card.